# Insert data into staging table in databse trigger on main table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have below requirement-

I have 2 tables Main Table A ,Staging table B

I have written a before insert trigger on main table A to check some wrong data. If the data is wrong then it will insert into staging table B so that user can view the errors and correct then and then again upload the data.
My issue is -Data is not getting inserted into staging table as I am using raise_form_trigger_failure just after insert statement.Is there any other way to do this?

TRIGGER CODE-

```
create or replace trigger CCM_TEST 
   before insert OR UPDATE ON "CCM_MANAGER" 
   for each row 
    declare
  l_user varchar2(500);
  v_user number;
  v_cost_centre number;
  v_company_code number;
  v_show_error varchar2(100);
begin  
l_user := NVL(v('APP_USER'), user);
   if inserting then 

           begin 
            select count(1)
            into v_cost_centre
            From gl_code_combinations
            where segment2=:new.cost_center
            and enabled_flag ='Y';

            if (v_cost_centre= 0) then    
             v_show_error:='Cost Centre does not exists!!  '||'Cost Centre -'||:new.cost_center;      
             :new.CHECK_INSERT_FLAG:='Y';

              Insert into CCM_MANAGER_STG(COMPANY_CODE,
              COST_CENTER,
              USER_NAME,
              EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
              EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
              CREATED_BY,
              CREATION_DATE,
              LAST_UPDATED_BY,
              LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
              LINE_ID,
              CHECK_INSERT_FLAG,
              SHOW_ERRORS) values
              ( :new.COMPANY_CODE,
              :new.COST_CENTER,
              :new.USER_NAME,
              :new.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
              :new.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
              :new.CREATED_BY,
              :new.CREATION_DATE,
              :new.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
              :new.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
              :new.LINE_ID,
              :new.CHECK_INSERT_FLAG,
              v_show_error);
              end if;
            raise_application_error (-20001, 'Cost Centre does not exists!!  '||'Cost Centre -'||:new.cost_center||' ');                              
          exception
            when others then
            --raise_application_error (-20001, sqlerrm);
            null;

      end;

       begin 
            select count(1)
            into v_company_code
            From gl_code_combinations
            where segment1=:new.company_code
            and enabled_flag ='Y';

            if (v_company_code= 0) then   

             v_show_error:='Company Code does not exists!!'; 
             :new.CHECK_INSERT_FLAG:='Y';

              Insert into CCM_MANAGER_STG(COMPANY_CODE,
              COST_CENTER,
              USER_NAME,
              EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
              EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
              CREATED_BY,
              CREATION_DATE,
              LAST_UPDATED_BY,
              LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
              LINE_ID,
              CHECK_INSERT_FLAG,
              SHOW_ERRORS) values
              ( :new.COMPANY_CODE,
              :new.COST_CENTER,
              :new.USER_NAME,
              :new.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
              :new.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
              :new.CREATED_BY,
              :new.CREATION_DATE,
              :new.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
              :new.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
              :new.LINE_ID,
              :new.CHECK_INSERT_FLAG,
              v_show_error);
           end if;

               raise_application_error (-20001, 'Company Code does not exists!!  '||'Company code -'||:new.company_code||' ');
             --  Rollback;
           exception
            when others then
            raise_application_error (-20001, sqlerrm);
            null;
          end;
     end if; 

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

First way is `autonomous transaction`.

Second way is `compound trigger`.

Comment: I am trying with autonomous transactions and its getting saved into the staging table but its also getting saved in the main table as well. If the data stored into staging table then it should not be saved into main table as User will correct the data then again will upload it. If I try raise_application_error just after insert statement then it error out for every record and nothing is saved into main table.

Comment: @user3849885 show me the code with autonomous transaction please